# How to know the Android version remotely

Tags: android, version, imei, android-version

In our case, we have a lot of android POS devices deployed on ground already that we don't know every device's current android version but we have their IMEI serials and android IDs.

Is there any lookup tool or API that get their android versions through entering the device's IMEI or Android ID ?

I'm trying to get their android versions remotely without having to develop any further features on these devices.

I have searched for a lookup tool but without luck

Comment: IMEI and Android ID are independent of the OS version. But if the clients contact your server you should check the used HTTP headers for it's User-Angent. May be it contains the data you are searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If android devices are sending requests to your server then you can check `user-agent` data on server side to get some details about the device. Something like what [whatsmyua](https://www.whatsmyua.info) is doing.
Since you didn't mention your server side programming language, i cann't give you more info about how to do it.